# Can I install Ubuntu Server on E5-2650 v2?

Tags: server, cpu

I wanna build a server and wanted to know if I can install Ubuntu Server on a server that runs with this CPU:
Intel XeonE5-2650 v2

Comment: Why do you think it wouldn't?

Answer (score 1):

Normally the proessor is the least of your wories when build a Linux system of any flavour. The most common form of complaints are getting the graphics card working. This will not be the case for a Ubuntu Server. So I expect you to have no problems.

Depending on what has been on the box previously, you may have to disable secure boot in the bios. But I would try it first.

Good luck